# How to customize the header titles of the List Views web part without renaming the List?

Tags: 2007, list, list-view

Suppose I have a List 'Pending registrations' as shown below. Using the List View web part, it will display the following header titles such as 'Title', 'User' and 'Status'.

Are there ways to rename the header titles **without renaming the column name for the List**? (for example changing the 'Status' to 'Stage')

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by customizing the associated XSLT in designer. Assuming this question is for MOSS 2007, list view webpart can be customized in designer. Select the webpart, right click and you will see an option to generate XSLT(I am not sure of the exact wordings in the menu) which can be used to modify the look and feel of the webpart completely.

If its 2010, a completely new custom XSLT could be configured for the webpart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to place a "Content Editor WebPart" on to the page below - and insert some javascript / JQuery to update the displayname of the column.

Comment: Is it possible to include the javascript / JQuery that you will use to update the display name of the column to your answer to make it complete?