# Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page ... & Error: Reference to undefined entity 'nbsp'

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I created a page in SharePoint Designer 2007 that use a SharePoint Library. I used the method of 'generating XSLT' from this page - [How to customize the header titles of the List Views web part without renaming the List?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43597/how-to-customize-the-header-titles-of-the-list-views-web-part-without-renaming-t)

At first, the page did work as expected. However, after a long while, the page fail to work and display the following message (at the **Internet Explorer**):

`Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.`

So, I went to open the page in the **SharePoint designer** and notice the following error:

`This Web Part does not have a valid XSLT stylesheet:
Error: Reference to undefined entity 'nbsp'.`

So, my question is:

[A] What are the causes that result in such error message (even though that it is working in the first place)?

[B] What are the solution or workaround to solve and prevent such error message from occurring again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the problem.

Simply change the `&nbsp` to `&#160` for the XSLT code will solve this problem.

Comment: - This solution really works, thanks. - Yet I´m still wondering how to define and use entities (as "&nbsp;") in an Xslt List View Web Part. Using entity number notation (as "&#160;") is still rather awkward and less readable...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a typo and included `nbsp` somewhere in your XSLT, instead of `&nbsp`. Correcting that should fix the issue.

`&nbsp` is an entity used to declare non-breaking space in HTML. I suggest you do a search for `nbsp` and change it to `&nbsp` in your XSLT.