# "Unable to display this Web Part" error occured

Tags: error, newform

My colleague's STS site suddenly showed this error when she tried to add New Item.

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID: Some GUID

It has worked until today for a month and I haven't made any change in the source.

I have checked on the internet and found the following solution on this forum:
[Unable to display this Web Part - using data form web part with grouping and large list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71684/unable-to-display-this-web-part-using-data-form-web-part-with-grouping-and-lar)

My source looked similar to this, so I changed the `&nbsp;` to `&#160;`. However the error still came up and couldn't open the New Item.

I have no clue to this error because it suddenly happened. (I am not the one who customised the source.)

Comment: Did you check the Logs using the Correlation GUID to get more Information about the Problem eg which Webpart causes the error?

Comment: Hi Leopold, thanks for your comment! I don't think I checked the logs. Can you tell me where to find them?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the resources the webpart is using has the right permissions.

> For Eg. The webpart may be accessing data from site assets/style
>   library etc. So check the permissions of user on the corresponding
>   library from webpart.

If the user doesn't have the necessary permission then you won't be able to see the web part n SP will give you error "Unable to display this Web Part"

It Worked for me. Check!